# How do I get a discord bot to add a reaction to its own reply?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Expected Result: The user comments 'fruit', the bot responds with 'apple' and leaves an apple emoji  on **its own comment**

Actual Result: The user comments 'fruit', the bot responds with 'apple' and leaves an apple emoji  on **the user's comment instead**

```
bot.on('message', msg => {

  if(msg.content === 'fruit'){

    msg.reply('apple').then();
    msg.react('');

  }

})
```

I've also tried the following:

```
 bot.on('message', msg => {

  if(msg.content === 'fruit'){

     msg.reply('apple').then(react(''));

  }

})
```

But it results in an error: 'react is not defined'

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is super easy to solve. All you have to do is use an arrow function inside the `.then`.

```
msg.reply('apple').then(m => m.react(''));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the result of the message reply inside the then of of the promise :

```
bot.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'fruit') {
    msg.reply('apple').then((botMsg) => botMsg.react(''));
  }
});
```

(You can have the message created inside the then, it means that the promise successed)